# OwnCloud: How to synchronyze the FileSystem with the DB

Tags: mysql, linux, owncloud

I have to "insert" a lot of files into an owncloud server (8.2). 
A user give me a USB key with the files and tell me to copy of all them into his owncloud data files repository.

Do you know if is it possible ? 
Is it possible to synchronyze the ownCloud data fileSystem with the ownCloud database?

My environment is Linux CentOS7 (Apache 2.4, mySQL 5.6, php 5.6)

Thanks,

Comment: Why don't you simply use the webdavs url for the target folder as offered by your owncloud installation? That way you can simply drag&drop all the files from the usb stick to the target folder inside owncloud. owncloud then takes care of the database.

Comment: In fact I want to copy some files to all my ownloud users accounts which I do not have passwords for WebDAV synchronizations.

Comment: Then take a look at the re-scan option documented here: https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.0/admin_manual/configuration_server/occ_command.html You should be able to drop the files into ownclouds file system and then use that command line tool to scan them.

Comment: Yep, just tried that myself, works like charm.

Comment: @arkascha If your proposed solution works, why not post it as an answer?

Comment: @AnthonyW Sure, might be more correct that way...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

owncloud brings a command line utility that allows to manually trigger some tasks. Among those is the `files:scan` function which re-scans a users file system.

So you can import those files by following these steps: 
 1. you copy the files into the physical file system of the user(s) inside ownclouds data folder
 2. you fire the command line utility to re-scan the files. That takes care to update the database according to the files found.

This is an example for the manual trigger:

```
sudo -u www-data php occ files:scan <user name>
```

Here `<user name>` obviously has to be replaced. Also the account name the `sudo` command switches to depends on the linux distribution and its setup. The command has to be started inside ownclouds base folder. THe command can be called in a loop with different user names, that can be done by means of standard scripting.

Here is a documentation of the utility: https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.0/admin_manual/configuration_server/occ_command.html

I just made a try myself using an owncloud-8.2 installation and succeeded.

Comment: Thank you very much @arkascha , the problem is resolved with this !

Answer (score 1):

Before I could sucessfully scan my files again as arkascha explained, I needed to change the ownder and the group of the new folder to www-data (for Debian OS - others see OC-Docu [1](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/9.0/admin_manual/configuration_server/occ_command.html)) and set rights of the new directory to 755

Change ownder:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data <path>
```

Change rights:

```
sudo chmod 755 <path>
```

whwere  is the path to the newly added directory and could for example look like this example: `/media/hdd/owncloud/data/<username>/files/<newFolderName>`

OC-Docu:
https://doc.owncloud.org/server/9.0/admin_manual/configuration_server/occ_command.html